# listview() not working jquerymobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm building an app using jquery mobile, I 'm adding content into ul tag using ajax but after loading the content the listview() function is throwing js error on console and is not working.

I've tested it with jquery.mobile-1.0rc1.min.js
jquery 1.5 and 1.6.

check my code:

```
var loaddata = function()
{
            var NPage  = $('#subCatView');

        var pContent = NPage.find('.content');
        pContent.empty();
        pContent.html('<ul></ul>');
        pList = pContent.find('ul');

        pList.html("<li>Test List Item</li>");
        pList.listview();
        $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
        return;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="subCatView" data-role="page"> 
  <div class="header" data-role="header" data-theme="a">
    <h1></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="content" data-role="content"></div> 
</div>
```

Erorr:

Error: c[0] is undefined
Source File: http://localhost/jquerymobile/jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0rc1.min.js
Line: 103

It is throwing error on **pList.listview();**, when I remove it, error remove, but obviously listview is not created.

When I use pList.listview('refresh');

I know refresh is used when we append more items.

Error: uncaught exception: cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try giving your `<ul>` an ID like:

```
<ul id='dataList1'></ul>
```

Then call:

```
$('#dataList1').listview('refresh');
```